# transferring application to iPad 2

Tags: xcode, ipad

I'm having a problem about transferring my application to ipad 2. At first i was using the Mac 10.6.8 with xcode 4.2 then it says that the ipad 2 is IOS of 5.1 but the xcode 4.2 is only up to IOS 5.0. And so now I'm using Mac 10.7.8 with Xcode 4.3. I already click the certificate for the keychain. And then I downloaded the provisioning file, double click it but the organizer says that "Valid identity not found". I went to Build settings and tried to change the code signing but I can't choose except the iphone developer, iphone distribution and the other "profile doesn't match any valid certificate/private key pair in the default key chain".

I cannot transfer all my app. Please help. :o

Answer (score 0):

Double check you have the followings:

1. Private key of your developer certificate (check in Keychain Access)
2. Developer certificate (check in Keychain Access)
3. Valid Provisioning Profile (either Team Provisioning Profile, or Provisioning Profile tied to your App ID, if you created it, check in xCode > Organizer > Provisioning Profile)